# How to export the schema of a MySql table into an XML file with Talend Open Studio for Data Integration?

Tags: mysql, talend

In Talend Open Studio for Data Integration I have the possibility to manually export the schema of a certain database table as an XML file.

I just have to hit the export button in the schema editor/viewer and it's done.

But how can I do this within a job? What's the corresponding component? Or are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

You need the following components:

- **tMysqlColumnList** (give it the table name in question)
- **tFixedFlowInput** (creates an input flow from given values/variables)
- some sort of output; **tLogRow** to demonstrate what you're getting and **tFileOutputXML** once you're happy)

The trick is to create the schema with what you want (e.g. column name, column type, is_nullable, etc) in tFixedFlowInput.
The column name can be anything you want, the Value has to be one of the global variables that **tMysqlColumnList** populates.

You can click on the Value column in **tFixedFlowInput** and hit control and space to see all variables available.
For example `((String)globalMap.get("tMysqlColumnList_1_DATA_TYPE"))` will give you the data type for each column.

Adding 2 fields to the schema like:

```
columnName ((String)globalMap.get("tMysqlColumnList_1_COLUMN_NAME"))
columnType ((String)globalMap.get("tMysqlColumnList_1_DATA_TYPE"))
```

will list all column names and their data types for that table.

If you want to iterate over a number of tables, you can precede all this with a **tMysqlTableList** and do something similar to iterate **tMysqlColumnList** on each result from the table list.

Hope that makes sense.

It'll be up to you to figure out the xml structure on output, but this will get you your column definitions.